How do i navigate back to the root index from within a nested route using expo router
I have a layout as such.
app/
  (auth)
      _layout.tsx
      index.tsx
      sign-in.tsx
  _layout.tsx
  dashboard.tsx
  index.tsx

from within sign-in.tsx i call router.replace("/") when i get an auth token, this navigates me to the index inside (auth) not the root index. So how can I navigate to the root index from within (auth)/signin.tsx?
found the open issue https://github.com/expo/router/issues/365

I don't know the exact priciple of the replace function in expo-router, but I guess it find the closest "/" page from current page.
so my solution looks like this.
(I'm not sure this is technically right.. but it works for me)
(+When you rebuttal, you are correct. I'm just rookie...)
=> make a new stack screen in the app directory to re-replace(?) with the "real" root page.
1. Make a new file at /app directory
(In my case, I made ResetToRoot.tsx)
/app
  /(tabs)
    - _layout.tsx
    - index.tsx
    - mypage.tsx
  - _layout.tsx
  - index.tsx
  - ResetToRoot.tsx

2. Add the stack screen in the root layout.
<Stack screenOptions={{....}}>
  <Stack.Screen name="index" />
  <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" />
  <Stack.Screen name="ResetToRoot" />
</Stack>

3. Replace the screen in ResetToRoot.tsx
    <ResetToRoot.tsx>

    import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    
    const ResetToRoot = () => {
      const router = useRouter();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          router.replace("/");
        }, 0);
      });
      return <></>;
    };
    
    export default ResetToRoot;

